# What result of uptime command means on android?

Tags: android, shell

I run uptime command on android shell and I get quit different result than for same command on Linux. What this result means exactly?

```
up time: 01:53:22, idle time: 00:37:26, sleep time: 01:08:02
```

up time is total time form boot. But what is difference between idle and sleep? 
and what is

```
time = uptime - idle_time - sleep_time
```

it's some kind of run time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried `watch -n 1 uptime` and did some tests: scrolling home screen, playing some game, locking, unlocking...

`uptime` - time from boot, it's clear

`idle` - when I wasn't touching my phone, next this time grows little bit even in some app/game, so it's probably classic linux idle = it grows when kernel, user and i/o are 0%

`sleep` - locked screen (but it grown very slowly, maybe it has beed disturbed by sshd, my connection and by calling *watch*` and *uptime*). In locked screen you should notice than CPU runs only with one core and the lowest frequency, for sure there is more "sleep" and power saving routines in this mode (at least display is off :))

`"rest time"` - probably when at least CPU has some work :)

Comment: Do you think that sleep and idle time have no common part of time? in anther words: if increase idle not increase sleep and inverse.

Comment: not 100% sure but no. More likely some processes are frequently interrupting the sleep mode... But now this is not based on experiment, just thought...

Comment: I get "uptime: 22 days, idle time: 33 days, sleep time: 13 days". If uptime is time from boot how can idle time be greater than it?